# Call function after returning from the background

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to call a function as soon as the person returns to the application when it is in the background, for example reloading messages, is there any way?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate.html

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, AppState } from 'react-native';

const YourTopLevelComponent = props => {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(null);

  const onAppStateChange = async (nextAppState) => {
    console.log(`onAppStateChange: appState from ${appState} to ${nextAppState}`);
    // cold start
    if (appState === null) {
      // do whatever you need on cold start
    }
    // come to foreground from background
    else if (appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      // do whatever you need on resume
    }
    setAppState(nextAppState);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', onAppStateChange);
    if (appState === null) {
      // The event is not triggered on cold start since the change has already taken place
      // therefore we need to call it manually.
      onAppStateChange(AppState.currentState);
    }
    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', onAppStateChange);
    };
  }, [appState]);

  return (
    <View>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};
```